# For loop not outputting correct results per formula

Tags: c++

I am trying to work on an assignment for a C++ course. The question is per below

> Create a C-program that prints two columns on the screen with the
>   temperature in degrees Fahrenheit and the equivalent temperature in
>   degrees Celsius.
>
> The left column shows the temperature in Fahrenheit. The right column
>   shows the temperature in Celsius.
>
> Start with 0 degrees Fahrenheit and proceed until 300 degrees
>   Fahrenheit. Take steps of 20 degrees. Print degrees Celsius with 1
>   position behind the comma (use “%10.1f” as format specifier). Also
>   print a header text.
>
> Make the program maintenance insensitive, which means that the start-
>   and end-temperature and the step size must be easy to adjust.

HEre is my code in C++

```
{
    // TEMPERATURE CONVERSION
    float celsius;
    float startrange;
    float endrange;
    float increment;

    printf("Enter start range in Fahrenheit \n");
    scanf("%f",&startrange);
    printf("Enter end range in Fahrenheit \n");
    scanf("%f",&endrange);
    printf("Enter increments in Fahrenheit \n");
    scanf("%f",&increment);

    float counter;

    for(counter=startrange; counter<endrange; counter = counter + increment)
    {
        celsius=(5.0/9.0)*(counter-32);
        printf("%f \t","%f \n",counter,celsius);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The CMD screen output just prints 0 for all results. Not sure whats wrong in my method - I am assigning user entered values to the inputs and the loop should just print the outputs.

Error I get is in the screengrab:

[image: https://imgur.com/a/kEEdiSD]

Comment: i know but the assignment asks to use C only for the first lecture (no iostream etc)

Comment: I'm sorry to inform you that you are learning C, not C++. `Create a C-program `. I suggest finding a different course. [Stop teaching C](https://youtu.be/YnWhqhNdYyk)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `printf` call uses `"%f \t"` as the format specifier, and passes string literal `"%f \n"` as the value to be formatted. Whereupon the program exhibits undefined behavior, as `%f` specifier expects an argument of type `double`, not `char*`

The third and fourth arguments - actual floating point values - don't have any corresponding format specifiers at all.

Comment: thanks Igor, I changed the print statements to   printf("%f \t",counter);
  printf("%f \n",celsius); and it works now. I dont follow your point on the third and fourth arguments?

Comment: your original code had 4 arguments, 1: "%f \t", 2: "%f \n", 3: counter, 4: celcius. For the printf function, the first argument is the format specifier and this specifier should specify the format for ALL arguments that follow. You probably meant: ```printf("%f \t %f \n", counter, celcius)```